# Lower bound on sizes of "sum" and "product" of a set of real numbers

Tags: discrete-mathematics, probabilistic-method

The problem is like this:

Let $A$ be a finite subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

Define $A+B = \{ a+ b \mid a \in A,\ b \in B\}$ and $A\cdot B = \{a \times\ b \mid a\in A, \ b\in B\}$

Prove that $$|A+A|\cdot|A\cdot A| \ge \frac{1}{64}|A|^{\frac{5}{2}}$$

#### My attempts

The only hint I have is to solve via probabilistic method. Another one is that $|A+A|$ is maximized when elements of $A$ in A.P and then $|A+A| \ge 2|A|-3$ and same for GP. But I could not use this property and the fact that it cant be an AP and GP simultaneously to show that their product is greater then what is to be proved.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `\cdot` will produce the multiplication dot you want, e.g. $A\cdot B$.

Comment: I'm confused, isn't $A\cdot B$ a subset of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$, not $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Sorry, I made a typo, corrected

Comment: Let A = {1}.  Then A+A = {2} and |{2}| = 1.  What do you think |S| means for any set S?

Comment: @WilliamElliot I did not get your question. Even in that case: $|A\cdot A| = |\{1\}| = 1$ and same way $|A+A|=1$. And the inequality is satisfied